# pyarrow's GcsFileSystem fails with "SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK"

Tags: python, ssl, pyarrow

I can't figure out how to use `pyarrow`'s `GcsFileSystem`.  It throws an `ArrowException: Unknown error: google::cloud::Status(UNKNOWN: Permanent error GetObjectMetadata: PerformWork() - CURL error [60]=SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK)` whatever I try.

Is there a minimal way to check if `GcsFileSystem` found the credentials and is able to authenticate?

I have the GCP JSON credentials file:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

Path(os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]).exists()
> True
```

The official Google storage client has no trouble authenticating and see blobs:

```
# The bucket and blob we care about.
bucket = "some-bucket"
blob_name = "path/to/file.parquet"
path = f"{bucket_name}/{blob_name}"


# The GCS client authenticates sees the object.
from google.cloud.storage import Client

Client().get_bucket(bucket).get_blob(blob_name).exists()
> True
```

But I can't create a `dataset` using `GcsFileSystem` using `pyarrow`:

```
from pyarrow.fs import GcsFileSystem
from pyarrow.dataset import dataset

# Create GcsGcsFileSystem instance.
# Should pick up credentials from `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var. 
gcs_fs = GcsFileSystem()

# Can't create a dataset.
ds = dataset(
    source=path,
    format="parquet",
    filesystem=gcs_fs,
)

> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ArrowException                            Traceback (most recent call last)

...
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyarrow/dataset.py:446, in _filesystem_dataset(source, schema, filesystem, partitioning, format, partition_base_dir, exclude_invalid_files, selector_ignore_prefixes)
    444     fs, paths_or_selector = _ensure_multiple_sources(source, filesystem)
    445 else:
--> 446     fs, paths_or_selector = _ensure_single_source(source, filesystem)
    448 options = FileSystemFactoryOptions(
    449     partitioning=partitioning,
    450     partition_base_dir=partition_base_dir,
    451     exclude_invalid_files=exclude_invalid_files,
    452     selector_ignore_prefixes=selector_ignore_prefixes
    453 )
    454 factory = FileSystemDatasetFactory(fs, paths_or_selector, format, options)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyarrow/dataset.py:413, in _ensure_single_source(path, filesystem)
    410 path = filesystem.normalize_path(path)
    412 # retrieve the file descriptor
--> 413 file_info = filesystem.get_file_info(path)
    415 # depending on the path type either return with a recursive
    416 # directory selector or as a list containing a single file
    417 if file_info.type == FileType.Directory:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyarrow/_fs.pyx:571, in pyarrow._fs.FileSystem.get_file_info()

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyarrow/error.pxi:144, in pyarrow.lib.pyarrow_internal_check_status()

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyarrow/error.pxi:138, in pyarrow.lib.check_status()

ArrowException: Unknown error: google::cloud::Status(UNKNOWN: Permanent error GetObjectMetadata: PerformWork() - CURL error [60]=SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK)
```

I can't use `GcsFileSystem` directly to get blob info either:

```
gcs_fs.get_file_info(path)

> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
ArrowException: Unknown error: google::cloud::Status(UNKNOWN: Permanent error GetObjectMetadata: PerformWork() - CURL error [60]=SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same exact issue but in c++, and turns out our Google Cloud SDK for C++ was old. Building a machine with latest SDK + arrow solved it - the same exact code runs there without an issue.
(actually taking a docker with latest arrow, curl and installing the sdk on top of it)

The error itself is coming from the curl the gcp sdk is using so installing latest solves it.